# Roll up multiple rows into one

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot-table

**I have a table that looks like this:**

```
USER_ID,ADDED_DATE,STATUS,COMPLETION_ID_TYPE,QA_OPTION,QA_OPTION_COUNT
12543,2020-06-01 00:00:00,qaComplete_L2,chart,Correct,3
12543,2020-06-01 00:00:00,qaComplete_L2,chart,Incorrect,3
12543,2020-06-12 00:00:00,qaComplete_L2,chart,Incorrect,1
12543,2020-06-12 00:00:00,qaComplete_L2,chart,Correct,1
```

**I want to display the results as:**

```
USER_ID ADDED_DATE  STATUS  COMPLETION_ID_TYPE  L2 Correct  L2 InCorrect
8388    6/01/20 0:00    qaComplete_L2   chart   3   3
8388    6/12/20 0:00    qaComplete_L2   chart   1   1
```

**I have tried this but not getting the results I am expecting:**

```
    select distinct user_id,
                         added_date,
                         status,
                         completion_id_type,
                         max(case
                                 when qa_option = 'Correct'
                                     then qa_option_count
                                 else 0
                             end) as L2_Correct,
                         max(case
                                 when qa_option = 'Incorrect' 
                                     then qa_option_count
                                 else 0
                             end) as L2_Incorrect

         from qa_report2
         where user_id = 12543
           and status = 'qaComplete_L2'
         group by user_id, status, added_date, completion_id_type,qa_option, qa_option_count
         order by user_id, added_date;

;
```

```
USER_ID,ADDED_DATE,STATUS,COMPLETION_ID_TYPE,L2_CORRECT,L2_INCORRECT
12543,2020-06-01 00:00:00,qaComplete_L2,chart,0,3
12543,2020-06-01 00:00:00,qaComplete_L2,chart,3,0
12543,2020-06-12 00:00:00,qaComplete_L2,chart,1,0
12543,2020-06-12 00:00:00,qaComplete_L2,chart,0,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there :)

I only removed the distinct and two last group by columns. Columns you need in the calculation, shouldn't appear in the group by clause, but only in the group function in the select clause.

So in the end, what I think you're looking for is:

```
select  user_id,
        added_date,
        status,
        completion_id_type,
        max(case
              when qa_option = 'Correct'
                then qa_option_count
              else 0
            end) as L2_Correct,
        max(case
              when qa_option = 'Incorrect' 
                then qa_option_count
              else 0
            end) as L2_Incorrect
from  qa_report2
where user_id = 12543
and   status = 'qaComplete_L2'
group by user_id,
         status,
         added_date,
         completion_id_type
         --,qa_option
         --,qa_option_count
order by user_id,
         added_date;
```

Note: You should be aware that you're using max(), I can imagine that if multiple records exist, you actualy want to use sum(), but that really depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PIVOT` to achieve it.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT USER_ID,
           ADDED_DATE,
           STATUS,
           COMPLETION_ID_TYPE,
           QA_OPTION_COUNT,
           QA_OPTION
      FROM QA_REPORT2
     WHERE USER_ID = 12543
       AND STATUS = 'qaComplete_L2'
) PIVOT (
    MAX ( QA_OPTION_COUNT )
    FOR QA_OPTION
    IN ( 'Correct' AS L2_CORRECT, 'Incorrect' AS L2_INCORRECT )
);
```